# riscv64-linux-gnu-ld: undefined reference to `fseek'

Tags: c, ubuntu, linker, riscv

Recently,I met with this problem under vmware ubuntu 22.04:
riscv64-linux-gnu-ld: loader.c:(.text.naive_uload+0x4c): undefined reference to `fseek' riscv64-linux-gnu-ld: loader.c:(.text.naive_uload+0x78): undefined reference to` fread'
riscv64-linux-gnu-ld: loader.c:(.text.naive_uload+0xbc): undefined reference to `fseek' riscv64-linux-gnu-ld: loader.c:(.text.naive_uload+0xe0): undefined reference to` fread'
I was using crossing compiler
My makefile is:

```
# Makefile for AbstractMachine Kernels and Libraries

### *Get a more readable version of this Makefile* by `make html` (requires python-markdown)
html:
    cat Makefile | sed 's/^\([^#]\)/    \1/g' | markdown_py > Makefile.html
.PHONY: html

## 1. Basic Setup and Checks

### Default to create a bare-metal kernel image
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),)
  MAKECMDGOALS  = image
  .DEFAULT_GOAL = image
endif

### Override checks when `make clean/clean-all/html`
ifeq ($(findstring $(MAKECMDGOALS),clean|clean-all|html),)

### Print build info message
$(info # Building $(NAME)-$(MAKECMDGOALS) [$(ARCH)])

### Check: environment variable `$AM_HOME` looks sane
ifeq ($(wildcard $(AM_HOME)/am/include/am.h),)
  $(error $$AM_HOME must be an AbstractMachine repo)
endif

### Check: environment variable `$ARCH` must be in the supported list
ARCHS = $(basename $(notdir $(shell ls $(AM_HOME)/scripts/*.mk)))
ifeq ($(filter $(ARCHS), $(ARCH)), )
  $(error Expected $$ARCH in {$(ARCHS)}, Got "$(ARCH)")
endif

### Extract instruction set architecture (`ISA`) and platform from `$ARCH`. Example: `ARCH=x86_64-qemu -> ISA=x86_64; PLATFORM=qemu`
ARCH_SPLIT = $(subst -, ,$(ARCH))
ISA        = $(word 1,$(ARCH_SPLIT))
PLATFORM   = $(word 2,$(ARCH_SPLIT))

### Check if there is something to build
ifeq ($(flavor SRCS), undefined)
  $(error Nothing to build)
endif

### Checks end here
endif

## 2. General Compilation Targets

### Create the destination directory (`build/$ARCH`)
WORK_DIR  = $(shell pwd)
DST_DIR   = $(WORK_DIR)/build/$(ARCH)
$(shell mkdir -p $(DST_DIR))

### Compilation targets (a binary image or archive)
IMAGE_REL = build/$(NAME)-$(ARCH)
IMAGE     = $(abspath $(IMAGE_REL))
ARCHIVE   = $(WORK_DIR)/build/$(NAME)-$(ARCH).a

### Collect the files to be linked: object files (`.o`) and libraries (`.a`)
OBJS      = $(addprefix $(DST_DIR)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(SRCS))))
LIBS     := $(sort $(LIBS) am klib) # lazy evaluation ("=") causes infinite recursions
LINKAGE   = $(OBJS) \
  $(addsuffix -$(ARCH).a, $(join \
    $(addsuffix /build/, $(addprefix $(AM_HOME)/, $(LIBS))), \
    $(LIBS) ))

## 3. General Compilation Flags

### (Cross) compilers, e.g., mips-linux-gnu-g++
AS        = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
CC        = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
CXX       = $(CROSS_COMPILE)g++
LD        = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ld
OBJDUMP   = $(CROSS_COMPILE)objdump
OBJCOPY   = $(CROSS_COMPILE)objcopy
READELF   = $(CROSS_COMPILE)readelf

### Compilation flags
INC_PATH += $(WORK_DIR)/include $(addsuffix /include/, $(addprefix $(AM_HOME)/, $(LIBS)))
INCFLAGS += $(addprefix -I, $(INC_PATH))

CFLAGS   += -O2 -MMD -Wall -Werror $(INCFLAGS) \
            -D__ISA__=\"$(ISA)\" -D__ISA_$(shell echo $(ISA) | tr a-z A-Z)__ \
            -D__ARCH__=$(ARCH) -D__ARCH_$(shell echo $(ARCH) | tr a-z A-Z | tr - _) \
            -D__PLATFORM__=$(PLATFORM) -D__PLATFORM_$(shell echo $(PLATFORM) | tr a-z A-Z | tr - _) \
            -DARCH_H=\"arch/$(ARCH).h\" \
            -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector \
            -Wno-main -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE
CXXFLAGS +=  $(CFLAGS) -ffreestanding -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions
ASFLAGS  += -MMD $(INCFLAGS)
LDFLAGS  += -z noexecstack

## 4. Arch-Specific Configurations

### Paste in arch-specific configurations (e.g., from `scripts/x86_64-qemu.mk`)
-include $(AM_HOME)/scripts/$(ARCH).mk

### Fall back to native gcc/binutils if there is no cross compiler
ifeq ($(wildcard $(shell which $(CC))),)
  $(info #  $(CC) not found; fall back to default gcc and binutils)
  CROSS_COMPILE :=
endif

## 5. Compilation Rules

### Rule (compile): a single `.c` -> `.o` (gcc)
$(DST_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@) && echo + CC $<
    @$(CC) -std=gnu11 $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $(realpath $<)

### Rule (compile): a single `.cc` -> `.o` (g++)
$(DST_DIR)/%.o: %.cc
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@) && echo + CXX $<
    @$(CXX) -std=c++17 $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $(realpath $<)

### Rule (compile): a single `.cpp` -> `.o` (g++)
$(DST_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@) && echo + CXX $<
    @$(CXX) -std=c++17 $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $(realpath $<)

### Rule (compile): a single `.S` -> `.o` (gcc, which preprocesses and calls as)
$(DST_DIR)/%.o: %.S
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@) && echo + AS $<
    @$(AS) $(ASFLAGS) -c -o $@ $(realpath $<)

### Rule (recursive make): build a dependent library (am, klib, ...)
$(LIBS): %:
    @$(MAKE) -s -C $(AM_HOME)/$* archive

### Rule (link): objects (`*.o`) and libraries (`*.a`) -> `IMAGE.elf`, the final ELF binary to be packed into image (ld)
$(IMAGE).elf: $(OBJS) am $(LIBS)
    @echo + LD "->" $(IMAGE_REL).elf
    @$(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(IMAGE).elf --start-group $(LINKAGE) --end-group

### Rule (archive): objects (`*.o`) -> `ARCHIVE.a` (ar)
$(ARCHIVE): $(OBJS)
    @echo + AR "->" $(shell realpath $@ --relative-to .)
    @ar rcs $(ARCHIVE) $(OBJS)

### Rule (`#include` dependencies): paste in `.d` files generated by gcc on `-MMD`
-include $(addprefix $(DST_DIR)/, $(addsuffix .d, $(basename $(SRCS))))

## 6. Miscellaneous

### Build order control
image: image-dep
archive: $(ARCHIVE)
image-dep: $(OBJS) am $(LIBS)
    @echo \# Creating image [$(ARCH)]
.PHONY: image image-dep archive run $(LIBS)

### Clean a single project (remove `build/`)
clean:
    rm -rf Makefile.html $(WORK_DIR)/build/
.PHONY: clean

### Clean all sub-projects within depth 2 (and ignore errors)
CLEAN_ALL = $(dir $(shell find . -mindepth 2 -name Makefile))
clean-all: $(CLEAN_ALL) clean
$(CLEAN_ALL):
    -@$(MAKE) -s -C $@ clean
.PHONY: clean-all $(CLEAN_ALL)
```

```
#HAS_NAVY = 1
RAMDISK_FILE = build/ramdisk.img

NAME = nanos-lite
SRCS = $(shell find -L ./src/ -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.S")
include $(AM_HOME)/Makefile

ifeq ($(ARCH),native)
ISA = am_native
else
INC_PATH += include $(NAVY_HOME)/libs/libc/include
endif

./src/resources.S: $(RAMDISK_FILE)
    @touch $@

ifeq ($(HAS_NAVY),)
files = $(RAMDISK_FILE) src/files.h src/syscall.h
# create an empty file if it does not exist
$(foreach f,$(files),$(if $(wildcard $f),, $(shell touch $f)))
else

ifeq ($(wildcard $(NAVY_HOME)/libs/libos/src/syscall.h),)
  $(error $$NAVY_HOME must be a Navy-apps repo)
endif

update:
    $(MAKE) -s -C $(NAVY_HOME) ISA=$(ISA) ramdisk
    @ln -sf $(NAVY_HOME)/build/ramdisk.img $(RAMDISK_FILE)
    @ln -sf $(NAVY_HOME)/build/ramdisk.h src/files.h
    @ln -sf $(NAVY_HOME)/libs/libos/src/syscall.h src/syscall.h

.PHONY: update
endif
```

I was fully unaware of what was happening.Who can help me,please!!!

Solve the cross compile link error

Comment: I have included <stdio.h>,but it seems useless...

Comment: Yeah, it's not headers that you need, but libraries — the error is coming from the linker not the compiler.  `fseek` is a standard C library function, so found in the standard C library.  Sharing the makefile is not really necessary, maybe share the actual linker command that is issued.

Comment: You posted the error text from the make. But, you left off the actual command that make was doing when the error occurred. We can't tell without seeing the command that was actually executed, but I notice that `-ffreestanding` was a possible option. This, and `RAMDISK_FILE = build/ramdisk.img` imply you're building a freestanding/bootable image file (that gets put into flash, or booted from a USB stick, etc.). `fseek` is provided by `libc`. But, there usually isn't a [full] `libc` for a standalone environment. Or, you need some `-L` and/or `-l` options on the linker command to find the libs

Comment: make -k ARCH=riscv32-nemu run  I use this command and I tried to use linux functions such as open and close to  replace fopen.. but I failed again...  riscv64-linux-gnu-ld: loader.c:(.text.loader.constprop.0+0x54): undefined reference to `read'
riscv64-linux-gnu-ld: loader.c:(.text.loader.constprop.0+0x8c): undefined reference to `close'